# What's the role of the pronoun "iis" in this context?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, ablative, dative, case

In lines 48-52 of chapter XVI of *Lingua latina per se illustrata. Familia Romana* one can read:

> Merīdīes dīcitur ea caelī pars ubi sōl merīdīe vidētur; pars contrāria septenriōnes appellātur ā septem stēllīs, quae semper in eā caelī parte stant. Iīs, quī ad septentriōnēs nāvigant, oriēns a dextrā est, ā sinistrā occidēns, merīdiēs ā tergō.

I can understand the meaning of the text, but I cannot figure out the grammatical role of the pronoun "iīs" in the second sentence. I'm not even sure if this is dative or ablative. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Dativus est! Eae, quae Latine discere vult, liber oerbergensis iucundus erit (erit = futurus est). "Dative of reference," ut nuncupant Allen & Greenough, quodammodo generaliter.

Comment: OK, @SebastianKoppehel, I suppose it corresponds to [378.2](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/dative-reference), since it's used to define a direction (to those who seal to the North, ...). But in this case, the person is denoted by a pronoun in the dative plural and not by a participle, as in the examples of Allen and Greenough.

Comment: Yes, this is often called the **Dative of the Person Judging**, which can be connected to the "Dative of Relation" (e.g. see https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Asmythp%3D378 ).  An example that is typically found in many Latin textbooks is the following one: _oppidum prīmum Thessaliae venientibus ab Ēpīrō_ (Caes. _civ_. 3. 80). The typical participle used in the dative is replaced here, in your example, by a dative pronoun (_Iīs_) plus a relative clause (_quī ad septentriōnēs nāvigant_). This is not surprising since they function similarly.

Comment: @Mitomino This would have been (and in fact still is) a fine answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is often called the **Dative of the Person Judging** (aka *Dativus iudicantis*; cf. also the "Dative of Relation": e.g. see this [link](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Asmythp%3D378)), which is sometimes considered as a specific case of the "Dative of Reference" (see Sebastian's comment). An example of this kind of dative that is often found in many Latin textbooks is the following one:

> oppidum primum Thessaliae ***venientibus** ab Epiro* (Caes. *civ.* 3. 80, 1).

The typical participle used in the dative case is replaced in your example from LLPSI by a dative pronoun (*Iis*) plus a relative subordinate clause (*qui ad septentriones navigant*). However, note that this is not surprising since both constructions can be claimed to function similarly. Cf. the example above from Caesar with "oppidum primum Thessaliae ***iis** qui veniunt ab Epiro*". Accordingly, a similar parallelism can be said to hold for your example:

> ***Iis** qui ad septentriones navigant...* ≈ ***Navigantibus** ad septentriones...*

Since these datives are quite external to the main predication, there are some scholars who have even classified the *dativus iudicantis* as a ["disjunct".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_(linguistics)) For example, see Baños Baños's (2021: 225-226) section "El dativo como disjunto" ('The dative as a disjunct'), included in his [*Sintaxis Latina*, vol. I (CSIC, Madrid)](http://libros.csic.es/product_info.php?products_id=1508). This Spanish author includes two different kinds of datives like the *dativus iudicantis* and "ethical datives" in a specific section on "disjunct datives", this inclusion being motivated by the fact that both datives are quite peripherical in the syntactic structure.

Finally, I think that it can be very useful for you, Charo, to take a look at this [pdf document](https://www.culturaclasica.com/lingualatina/valores.de.los.casos.pdf) in Spanish, which provides a nice summary of the grammar of Latin cases with examples from *Lingua latina per se illustrata*. (NB: your dative is exemplified on page 5 in the subsection "[5.5] Dativo de relación").

Comment: The document in Spanish is really useful!

Answer (score 3):

It's dative. "**To those**, who sail towards those seven stars, east is to the right, west is to the left, south is behind them.".